# When is an element central in the image of a Weil representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

While reading [**Lemma 3** of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4889.pdf), I encountered the following statement:

> Take a sufficiently large finite Galois
>   extension $F/K$ such that $\rho/F$ is unramified. Then $\rho(\operatorname{Frob}_F )$ is central in
>   $\rho(W_K)$, so the eigenspaces of $\operatorname{Frob}_F$ are $W_K$-subrepresentations.

I know that:

- $K$ is a local field, and so is $F$ I think,
- $W_K$ is the Weil group of $K$,
- $\rho$ is a Frobenious-semisimple Weil presentation over $K$
- $Frob_F$ is an arithmetic Frobenius element.

But what exactly does "central" mean in this context?  I have never encountered this term before.

Comment: I presume it means "lies in the centre", that is $\rho(\text{Frob}_F)$ commutes with all elements of $\rho(W_K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the image of $\mathrm{Frob}_F$ is in the centre of the image of $\rho$.

If $\rho:W_K\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ is a Weil representation, then the image of inertia is finite, so there is a finite extension $F/K$ such that $\rho|_F$ is unramified.

So $\rho|_F$ factors through $W_F/I_F =\langle\mathrm{Frob}_F\rangle$. A priori, $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_F)$ could be something like $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. However, the fact that $\rho$ is Frobenius semisimple, combined with Schur's lemma, means that $\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_F)$ must act by a (one-dimensional) character. In particular, it lies in the centre of the image of $\rho$.